# Should it be written due date or date due?

Tags: adjectives

Is it better to write: 
Please pay by due date or 
Please pay by date due?

Comment: Yes. It is better to write one of those. Either one. There is no difference; they're both fixed phrases.

Comment: So neither is betterer?

Comment: Each of them is the betterest.

Comment: "due date" is usual for babies, either will work for most other contexts.

Answer (score 2):

I concur with Mr. Lawler, but I would recommend inserting the definite article, particularly in the second example.

- Please pay by the due date.
- Please pay by the date due.

Comment: A word to the wise is sufficient